# Minimize vector indexing overhead

Tags: matlab, optimization, vector, indexing, vectorization

I have a vectorized function which calculates distance to a large set of points. To improve performance I am limiting the number of the points by selecting only the necessary ones. So instead of `distanceToPoint(points.x)` I am using `distanceToPoint(points.x(IDX))`. When I plot the computation time needed I can see that when the indexed part is more than %75 of the data it takes actually more time. What can I do to overcome this, or push the performance gain to say %85?
[image]

**EDIT:** I am adding the results after switching to logical indexing, obviously better. It seems there is a performance loss on the low %10 end however (visible if you view the images on top of each other)
[image]

Comment: Is your `IDX` composed of integers representing positions in your `points.x` or is it a logical array?

Comment: they are position integers returned from a `find(criteria)` function

Comment: Instead of `find`, try `IDX = points.x == criteria` (or whatever other logic defined `IDX`). That way you will create a logical array, which in many cases result in faster indexing

Comment: Thanks a lot, I added a plot of the results. Can you post your comment as an answer so that I can set it as answered?

Comment: Thanks, @zamazalotta, but I would suggest, if possible, that you post the actual code you used (or a simplified version) and accept your own answer. I believe that our discussion above, as it is, may not be perfectly clear for people coming here with the same problem.

Comment: If you care about thatlast 10% you could check to see if your logical array is less than 10% empty, if it is, calculate all points instead.

Comment: Have you tried precomputing points.x(IDX)?

Comment: Usually, that selection operation takes a lot of time because it creates another array for points.x. If you could somehow put them in a cell array, then since cells work with pointer you get rid of matrix copying.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure what's happening here is your indexing scheme is taking a small amount of time. No matter what method you choose, it will take some time, although there are better methods. Logical is always better than using a find statement, but perhaps even better is to just use the index directly. Here's some sample code I used to test stuff, along with the results. Note, I ran this using 2010, I think there's some kind of optimization that occurs in the higher values, but I'm not sure exactly what's going on there... It is clear that direct indexing seems a bit faster than using a logical, and should be much faster than some kind of a find statement.

```
function time_test
time_full_test=zeros(1e3,1);
time_part_test=zeros(1e3,1);
time_direct_indexing_full=zeros(1e3,1);
time_direct_indexing_part=zeros(1e3,1);
data=rand(1e5,1);

for i=1:1e3
    time_full_test(i)=complex_stuff(data);
    time_part_test(i)=complex_stuff(data,i*100);
    time_direct_indexing_full(i)=complex_stuff2(data);
    time_direct_indexing_part(i)=complex_stuff2(data,i*100);
end
figure;plot(time_full_test);hold all;plot(time_part_test);plot(time_direct_indexing_full);plot(time_direct_indexing_part)
legend('Full Time Logic','Part Time Logic','Full Time Direct','Part Time Direct')

function time=complex_stuff(input,max_val)
tic
if ~exist('max_val','var')
    mask=true(size(input));
else
    mask=false(size(input));
    mask(1:max_val)=true;
end
sin(input(mask).^2/4356.342).^63/345;
time=toc;

function time=complex_stuff2(input,max_val)
tic
if ~exist('max_val','var')
    max_val=length(input);
end
sin(input(1:max_val).^2/4356.342).^63/345;
time=toc;
```

[image]